# Data-binding only part of a DataSource with Kendo UI

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid, odata

I am using OData and Kendo UI to fetch data, expanding into relations, and presenting them in nested Kendo Grids. Because it seems all of this data is part of one data source, whenever any change happens anywhere in the data, the whole grid is regenerated.

I've [reproduced the problem using Northwind data here](http://dojo.telerik.com/ozOXu).

I have a master grid:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
                    dataSource: {
                        type: "odata",
                        transport: {
                            read: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Employees?$expand=Orders"
                        },
                        pageSize: 6,
                        serverPaging: true,
                        serverSorting: true
                    },
                    height: 550,
                    sortable: true,
                    pageable: false,
                    editable: "inline",
                    detailInit: detailInit});
```

and a detail grid with an add button.

```
function detailInit(e) {
    $("<div/>").appendTo(e.detailCell).kendoGrid({
                    dataSource: {
                        data: e.data.Orders.results,
                        schema: { ... }
                    },
                    editable: true,
                    columns: [ ... ],
                    toolbar: [{ name: "create", text: "Add Order" }]
                });
            }
```

If you expand one of the rows, then click *Add Order*, the expanded row is immediately collapsed. I've put this down to the entire grid being regenerated.

In [Telerik's example](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/hierarchy) this conveniently doesn't happen, a) because they are not editable grids and b) because they are separate endpoints and therefore separate datasources.

Can I force it to only databind the detail grid and prevent this happening?

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Comment: @ThilakRao No. It just doesn't work. In the end, I had to make a separate endpoint for the detail grid, even though it was unnecessary.

Comment: That's terrible, but I can understand your situation.